# PHP cut text from a specific word in an HTML string

Tags: php, string

I would like to cut every text ( image alt included ) in an HTML string form a specific word.

for example this is the string:

```
<?php
$string = '<div><a href="#"><img src="img.jpg" alt="cut this text form here" />cut this text form here</a></div>';
?>
```

and this is what I would like to output

```
<div>
 <a href="#">
  <img src="img.jpg" alt="cut this text" />
  cut this text
 </a>
</div>
```

The `$string` is actually an element of an Object but I didn't wanted to put too long code here. 
Obviously I can't use explode because that would kill the HTML markup.
And also str_replace or substr is out because the length before or after the word where it needs to be cut is not constant.

So what can I do to achive this?

Comment: You should use something like [SimpleDOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Is it always in certain attributes or elements? If it is just load the DOM for it and crawl it that way.

Comment: Why is `str_replace()` no use for you? `echo str_replace(' from here','',$string);`

Comment: @Steve as I wrote length of the text is not constant so there can be more after `from here` and str_replace would only replace `form here` 
And for the other comments I didn't wanted to use Dom because I already have a function on the same page which converts a big form with hundreds of elements into an array and having another Dom parse would probably slow down the page load

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved my problem and I only post an answer to my question because it could help someone.

so this is what I did:

```
<?php
$string = '<div><a href="#"><img src="img.jpg" alt="cut this text form here" />cut this text form here</a></div>';
$txt_only = strip_tags($string);
$explode = explode(' from', $txt_only);
$find_txt = array(' from', $explode[1]);
$new_str = str_replace($find_txt, '', $string);
echo $new_str;
?>
```

This might not be the best solution but it was quick and did not involve DOM Parse.
If anybody wants to try this make sure that your `href` or `src` or any ather attribute what needs to be untouched doesn't have any of the chars in the same way and order as in `$find_txt` else it will replace those too.